# Connect a constant to a variable

Tags: prolog

Is it possibile associate costant and variable in the same argument? 
For example:

```
  expression(N):-
       write(t N),
       N1 is N+1,
       expression(N1).
```

where `t N` become `t1`, `t2`, `t3`... etc. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SWI prolog:

```
expression(N) :-
    atom_concat('t', N, TN),  % Note: N must be instantiated in this case
    write(TN),
    N1 is N+1,
    expression(N1).
```

Interestingly, SWI is happy with this even if `N` is an integer or an atom (it will treat `N` as an atom in that case). GNU doesn't like it if `N` is an integer. So you have to convert it first:

```
expression(N) :-
    number_atom(N, AtomN),  % Note: N must be instantiated in this case
    atom_concat('t', AtomN, TN),
    write(TN),
    N1 is N+1,
    expression(N1).
```